# Practical applications of Sobolev spaces

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, big-list, sobolev-spaces

What are the examples of *practical* applications of Sobolev spaces?

The framework of Sobolev spaces is very useful in the theoretical analysis of PDEs and variational problems: the questions of existence, stability and regularity of solutions, convergence of numerical methods etc. But what are the examples of *less theoretical* uses of Sobolev spaces?
In particular, what are the examples of

- PDEs whose explicit solution can only be found using the theory of Sobolev spaces
- problems when Sobolev spaces are an essential ingredient of otherwise impossible computation of some physically relevant quantity (heat flux, drag force etc.)
- PDEs from Physics (or other areas) when the solutions are not smooth but are Sobolev (by nature of the problem).

Remark. Maybe this has to be a community wiki question.

Answer (score 4):

Formulating optimization/control problems in Sobolev spaces often lead to better numerically conditioned problems, and more practically implementable solutions.

E.g: Consider the problem of devising efficient fluid mixing techniques:

Foures, D. P. G., C. P. Caulfield, and Peter J. Schmid. "Optimal mixing in two-dimensional plane Poiseuille flow at finite Péclet number." Journal of Fluid Mechanics 748 (2014): 241-277.

Available at https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/52899232.pdf

The core idea being that rather than trying to mix at all (fourier/wavelength) scales equally well , it is better to formulate the cost function that penalizes large scale inhomogenities more than fine variations in concentration.

Answer (score 0):

What about the [Eikonal equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation)
$$
|\nabla u| = 1?
$$
As far as I understand, one can construct solutions directly, but still, the solution does not have the desired classical regularity in general but only weak solutions with regularity in some Sobolev space.